# how to abort a python build phase script in xcode

Tags: python, xcode

I'm writing a build phase script in xcode using python.

I want to abort building when the script encounters an error en increment the error count in xcode.

What would be the way to do that ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
aStringThatShouldNotBeEmpty = ""

if not aStringThatShouldNotBeEmpty:
    # abort build process and print error in issue navigator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xcode expects a non-zero exit code as failure.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

aStringThatShouldNotBeEmpty = ""

if not aStringThatShouldNotBeEmpty:
    # abort build process and print error in issue navigator
    print 'Your own error, write whatever you want'
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: sys.exit( 'Your own error, write whatever you want' ) works as well